# INNER JOIN em duas tabelas diferentes

Tags: php, mysql

como vão?
Preciso de um Help de vocês rsrs...então

Estou com duas tabelas: a primeira é a tabela PESSOAS e é dela que preciso que me retorne a pessoa que não estiver na tabela VISTO.

Como mostra na imagem a ID 2 da tabela PESSOAS foi lá na tabela VISTO e marcou a ID 1 E 4 no campo PARA, então preciso que retorne para mim apenas a APP_LOVE_ID numero 3 pois foi a única que não foi marcada por ele e já que é a ID 2 que está indo lá e marcando ela também não pode aparecer.

Deu pra entender ou vacalhei a zorra toda? rsrs

O código que estou usando é mais ou menos esse:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM PESSOAS INNER JOIN VISTO ON PESSOAS.app_love_id != '2' and VISTO.de !='2'";
$resultado = $banco_de_dados->query($sql);
if ($resultado->num_rows > 0) { 
while($pessoa = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
$distancia =  $pessoas["app_love_distancia"]; /* AQUI TEM QUE VIR A APP_LOVE_DISTANCIA 222 */
}
}
```

[image: segue exemplo]

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Estava a pensar que seria mais uma coisa assim: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4173a1/4

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Segue uma sugestão para testes utilizando o operador *Exists* para verificar se a pessoa não existe na tabela Visto:

```
SELECT * FROM PESSOAS 
WHERE
    PESSOAS.ID <> 2 AND
    NOT EXISTS 
        (SELECT * FROM VISTO 
         WHERE 
             VISTO.DE = 2 AND
             VISTO.PARA = PESSOAS.ID)
```

Comment: Nossa exatamente o que eu procurava , brilhou amigo! muito, muito obrigado 
imex

Comment: Estava a pensar que seria mais uma coisa assim: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4173a1/4

Answer (score -2):

Sua pergunta ficou tão confusa quanto seu`SELECT` que acredito que deveria ser:

`SELECT pessoas.*, visto.* FROM pessoas INNER JOIN visto ON pessoas.app_love_id = visto.de  WHERE pessoas.app_love_id <> 2 OR visto.de <> 2`

Comment: Brigadãoooooo mais não funcionou :( ... vou resumir:

Tenho uma tabela chamada USUÁRIO e cada uma delas tem uma ID e existem vários usuários dentro dessa tabela.

Tenho outra tabela chamada VOTOS e lá iremos colocar a  ID do USUÁRIO e suponhamos que ela esteja vazia.

O USUÁRIO com a ID 7 da um VOTO no USUÁRIO da ID 9 e outro voto pra ID 10 ,então na tabela VOTOS vai aparecer o voto, ou seja que o ID 7 deu voto pro ID 9 e ID 10.

Preciso que o USUÁRIO da ID 7 continue votando porem NÃO PODE MAIS APARECER PARA ELE VOTAR NA ID 9 E ID 10 POIS ELE JÁ VOTOU NELES.